# Unexpected output in the C code with union

Tags: c, unions

I don't understand the output in the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   union U
   {
      int i;
      char s[3];
   } u;
   u.i=0x3132;
   printf("%s", u.s);
   return 0;
}
```

Initial memory is `32` bits and is the binary value of `0x3132` which is

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0001 0011 0010`.

If the last three bytes of `0x3132` are the value of `s` (without leading zeroes), then `s[0]=0011,s[1]=0001,s[2]=0011`.

This gives the values of `s=0011 0001 0011=787`.

**Question**: Why the output is `21` and not `787`?

Comment: `u.s` is not a string and you cannot use `%s` to print that. That is technically undefined behaviour. Having said that, consider that `0x31 == 49 == '1'` and `0x32 == 50 == '2'` and hopefully that should be clear to you.

Comment: The last two groups of 8 bits are (in little-endian) `0011 0010` and `0011 0001` which in hex are `32` and `31` which in ASCII are `'2'` and `'1'`.

Comment: Assuming sizeof(int) is 4 without any padding bits and the byte ordering is little endian, and ascii encoding, then this behavior is defined.

Comment: Why do think it should be "`787`"?

Comment: you need to take `Endian`ness into account when laying out the expected order of the bits in the `int` field.    
Note: the `%s` format specifier stops when it sees a `0x00` character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first see this code sample:

```
#include <inttypes.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    union{
        int32_t i32;
        uint32_t u32;

        int16_t i16[2];
        uint16_t u16[2];

        int8_t i8[4];
        uint8_t u8[4];
    } u;

    u.u8[3] = 52;
    u.u8[2] = 51;
    u.u8[1] = 50;
    u.u8[0] = 49;

    printf(" %d %d %d %d \n", u.u8[3], u.u8[2], u.u8[1], u.u8[0]); // 52 51 50 49
    printf(" %x %x %x %x \n", u.u8[3], u.u8[2], u.u8[1], u.u8[0]); // 34 33 32 31
    printf(" 0x%x \n", u.i32); // 0x34333231

    return 0;
}
```

the union here is just to access the memory of `u` in 6 different ways.
you may use `u.i32` to read or write as `int32_t` or
you may use `u.u32` to read or write as `uint32_t` or

you may use `u.i16[0]` or `u.i16[1]` to read or write as `int16_t` or 
you may use `u.u16[0]` or `u.u16[1]` to read or write as `uint16_t` or

or like this to write as `uint8_t`:

```
u.u8[3] = 52;
u.u8[2] = 51;
u.u8[1] = 50;
u.u8[0] = 49;
```

and read like this as `int8_t`:

```
printf(" %d %d %d %d \n", u.u8[3], u.u8[2], u.u8[1], u.u8[0]);
```

then output is:

```
52 51 50 49
```

and read as `int32_t`:

```
printf(" 0x%x \n", u.i32);
```

then output is:

```
0x34333231
```

so as you see in this sample code union shares one memory place with many names/types.

in your sample code `u.i=0x3132;` this writes `0x3132` inside `u.i` memory, and depending on endianness of you system which is little-endian here, then you asked  `printf("%s", u.s);` from compiler, so u.s is array of type `char` meaning constant pointer to char type, so this `printf("%s", u.s);` will reads `u.s[0]` and prints that on the output `stdout` then reads `u.s[1]` and prints that on the output `stdout` and so on ..., until one of this  `u.s[i]` is zero.
this is what your code doing, so if none of u.s[0], u.s[1], u.s[2], u.s[3] not zero, then memory outside of your union will be read until one zero found or system memory fault `error` happens.

Answer (score 4):

The value 0x3132 is represented in memory as: 0x32 , 0x31 , 0x0 , 0x0, because the byte order is in little endian.

The printf call prints out the string represented by the member of the union `s`. The string is printed out byte by byte. First 0x32 and then 0x31 which are the ascii values for the characters: `'2'` and `'1'`. Then the printing stops as the third element is the null character: 0x0.

Note that the representation of int is implementation defined and may not consist of 4 bytes and may have padding. Thus the member of the union `s` may not represent a string, in which case calling printf with the `%s` specifier will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I accidentally must have pushed the downvote button, please edit your post so I can change this into an upvote =)

Comment: Sorry about that =)

Answer (score 1):

It means that you machine is *little-endian*, so the bytes are stored in the opposite order, like this:

```
32 31 00 00
```

So: `s[0] = 0x32, s[1] = 0x31, s[2] = 0x00.`

Even if in theory printing an array of chars using `"%s"` is undefined behaviour, this works, it prints `0x32 (character '2')`, `0x31 (character '1')` and then it stops a 0x00.

Answer (score 0):

if you write your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    union U
   {
      int i;
      char s[3];
   } u;

   u.i=0x3132;
   printf("%s", u.s);
   printf( "%8x\n", (unsigned)u.i);
}
```

Then you would see that the contents of u.i is 0x0000000000003132, which would actually be stored as: 0x3231000000000000 due to Endianness

and 0x00 is not a printable character, so the output from the second call to `printf()` is `<blank><blank><blank><blank><blank><blank>3132`  as you would expect

and the ascii char `1` is 0x31  and ascii char `2` is 0x32  and the first 0x00 stops the %s operations, so the first `printf()` outputs `21`.